# PHP/PDO: Problems creating array of values programmatically for Insert statement

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

I'm trying to create a reusable function that will work with almost any table, but I'm having trouble creating the array of values that will be passed in for the prepared parameters.

```
function insertInto($data, $table) {
  foreach($data as $key => $val) {
    if($key !== 'submit') {
          $tableFields .= "{$key},"; 
          $tablePrepare .= ":{$key},";
          $tableValues[] .= ${$key};
          ${$key} = "{$val}";
          echo "<br>\${$key} = ${$key}";
    }
  }
  $tableFields = substr($tableFields, 0, -1);
  $tablePrepare = substr($tablePrepare, 0, -1);
  print_r($tableValues);
  $sql = "INSERT INTO $table($tableFields) VALUES($tablePrepare)";  
  echo "<br>\$sql = $sql";
  $stmt = DB::prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute($tableValues);
  echo "<br>Record inserted successfully"; 
}
```

Everything works except $tableValues. When I submit some test data the echo statements display the following:

```
$player = Muller
$era = 1.58
$baa = .225
$whip = 0.78
$win = 36
$innings = 98.2

Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => )
$sql = INSERT INTO clash_pitchers(player,era,baa,whip,win,innings)
       VALUES(:player,:era,:baa,:whip,:win,:innings)
Record inserted successfully
```

This is the section that isn't working correctly

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => )
```

I considered creating bindParam/bindValue for each variable, but I ran into a similar issue. I'm sure there are flaws to my approach, so I'm definitely up for suggestions on a better way to achieve my goal, if this is even possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would have thought you don't need to do anything with the values array, just pass it straight in `$stmt->execute($data);`

Comment: What's the dot doing in `$tableValues[] .= ${$key};`?

Comment: Besides you need `key => value` pairs for the `execute()` so change it in `$tableValues[$key] = $val;`

Comment: @NigelRen When I pass the $data in directly (which is the $_POST array) I get the following error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined' in /<path>/functions.php:211 Stack trace: #0 /<path>/functions.php(211): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 /<path>/index.php(5): insertInto(Array, 'clash_pitchers') #2 {main} thrown in /<path>/functions.php on line 211 <= Line 211 is   $stmt->execute($data); I changed the Submit input to a button to hopefully have it excluded from the $_POST array, but error indicates otherwise.

Comment: @Michel Removing the dot gives this error: "Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'player' cannot be null' "

Comment: The dot shouldn't be there. Keep the change, remove the dot and see if it works

Comment: @Michel When I change it to $tableValues[$key] .= $val; (keeping the dot, but making the other change) it works! Awesome. If you submit that as the answer I'll give you credit for it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237459/discussion-between-user3561924-and-michel).

Answer (score 0):

@Michel was able to answer this question for me. As soon as he posts an answer, I'll give him credit for it. In the meantime, I wanted to post the answer outside of our comments back and forth, because it gets hidden currently and you have to view additional comments to see it.

So changing this line:

```
$tableValues[] .= ${$key};
```

To this:

```
$tableValues[$key] = $val;
```

is what fixed it.

Comment: So this looks like you are copying the data from `$data` to `$tableValues`, the only thing you are doing is removing the submit (`unset($data['submit');`)